# Mixing a mysql column with an interval?

Tags: mysql

The column `last_ran` has a datatype of datetime and `frequency` is set as: "1 day" or "1 week" or "1 month" or "1 year"...

Here is the MySQL statement I am trying to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM `cron_jobs` WHERE NOW() > `cron_jobs`.`last_ran` + INTERVAL `cron_jobs`.`frequency` LIMIT 1
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: You can't prepare a query this way. Just store the quantity and the scale separately

Comment: `INTERVAL` what? You need to specify what kind of interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the interval type:

```
INTERVAL `cron_jobs`.`frequency` SECOND
```

The `INTERVAL` command takes a specific form and string-expansion interpolation is not performed. Each argument must be expressed in the SQL. You could always inject this in your application layer, but be careful, split that up into a placeholder value when possible.

You'll need to specify your intervals in terms of seconds, days, or whatever, using only one unit, so day may become 86400 seconds, roughly. This will slowly drift around due to things like Daylight Saving.

If you're using days months and years don't have a specific length, so be careful.